# Nextcloud internal server error Remote Address: 172.18.0.1 Request ID

Tags: angular, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, nextcloud

Below is my docker-compose file.

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 11111111
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud/univention-app:14.0.6-0
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: 'nextcloud'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '11111111'
      POSTGRES_HOST: 'db'
      NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_USER: admin
      NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
  frontend:
    image: frontend:v1
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
      - nextcloud
      - middleware
    links:
      - db
      - nextcloud
      - middleware
    build: .
    ports: 
      - 3000:3000
  middleware:
    image: middleware:v1
    depends_on:
      - db
      - nextcloud
    links:
      - db
      - nextcloud
    ports:
      - 5000:80
```

My Nextcloud docker is running file on the port 8080, I was able to configure it with the Database name, password, user etc. And I updated the client id and secret from the Nextcloud, in my front end angular application call the nextcloud and get the token. I am getting an error as below when when the call to get the token is happening.

[image]

When I check in the browser console, I am getting the errors as preceding.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: oc_appconfig is not defined
    at merged-share-backend.js?v=3b8086fb-0:24
    at merged-share-backend.js?v=3b8086fb-0:80
merged-template-prepend.js?v=3b8086fb-0:1458 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
    at Object.filePath (merged-template-prepend.js?v=3b8086fb-0:1458)
    at viewer.js?v=3b8086fb-0:15
```

Anyone else faced this issue? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

please check your logs in the nextcloud docker config path /log. There should be 2 folders there: nginx & php. Normally the php should not be a problem (you would receive another error earlier if this would be the case).

In my case I had a problem with the permissions for the /path/to/data: they were not created correctly since when I first create the docker I forgot to give the PGID and the PUID correctly.

I was using the nextcloud docker from linuxserver.io